# How To Set Default Action on Mvc Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I would like to just set default action to call when use visit the site

**Example:**

When he type www.abc.com

He should view www.abc.com/somecontroller/someaction

> But the path should not be shown which is
>   **/somecontroller/someaction**

Please help me I have tried this

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But this also shows the complete path.
Thankyou.

Comment: In `Begin_Request`, check if the URL has no controller and action, then you can redirect to `someController/someAction`. Now consider that user clicks on `Home` button or clicks on site logo that redirects to home page, your url would be like `abc.com/home`.